# Radio button is showing div on selection but not hiding after selecting a different radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs I want to show based on a radio selection. I've written the below script, but the problem I've run into is the div doesn't hide after a different radio button is selected. I'm using ucalc so I can't change the class names or ids of the divs or the radio buttons so have to work with that.

Note, the radio button is automatically selected when the form loads so the first div needs to be showing initially.

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // First Div/Radio Button
    $('#input_radio-30-0-des').on('change', function(){ 
        var a = $(this).prop('checked');
        if(a) {
            $("#grid-40-42").show();
        } else {
            $("#grid-40-42").hide();
        }
    });

    // Second Div/Radio Button
    $("#grid-44-46").hide();
    $('#input_radio-30-1-des').on('change', function(){ 
        var a = $(this).prop('checked');
        if(a) {
            $("#grid-44-46").show();
        } else {
            $("#grid-44-46").hide();
        }
    });

    // Third Div/Radio Button
    $("#grid-46-48").hide();
    $('#input_radio-30-2-des').on('change', function(){ 
        var a = $(this).prop('checked');
        if(a) {
            $("#grid-46-48").show();
        } else {
            $("#grid-46-48").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

I'm not very familiar with writing javascript (you can probably tell!) so an explanation for 'dummies' would be appreciated!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Liv` what is **id** of third **div**? because of `2nd` and `3rd` div ids are same..

Comment: Can you change IDS names or add extra attributes? This way you can toggle using the same selector matching each radio with it's targeted div...

Comment: @RaeeshAlam sorry I copied it wrong - the id of the third div is #grid-46-48

Comment: @Bilel no unfortunately I can't as I'm using a builder called ucalc.pro and it doesn't allow for you to add extra class names or attributes

Comment: `@Liv` Check my below snippet so I have fixed your issue and now working fine as your query description there is not `ids` or `classes` changed.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam it looks like the css display:none is being crossed out for the second and third divs - and I can't use !important as this makes them not appear at all. Is there a way to override this but still allow the javascript to work?

Comment: @LivStrawbridge in my answer, I assume they are all hidden by default...

Comment: `@Liv` If you don't want to `display:none` by css then you can hide div by jQuery like `$('#grid-44-46, #grid-46-48').hide();` put before `on change event`.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam - that worked! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `hide` `2nd` & `3rd` div by `CSS` and when user change other button then find `ID` so according to `ID` show that div and rest div will `hide` as below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#input_radio-30-0-des, #input_radio-30-1-des, #input_radio-30-2-des').on('change', function(){ 
    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    if (getid=='input_radio-30-0-des') {
      $('#grid-44-46, #grid-46-48').hide()//2nd and 3rd div hide
      $("#grid-40-42").show();
    }
    if (getid=='input_radio-30-1-des') {
      $('#grid-40-42, #grid-46-48').hide()//1st and 3rd div hide
      $("#grid-44-46").show();
    }
    if (getid=='input_radio-30-2-des') {
      $('#grid-40-42, #grid-44-46').hide()//1st and 2rd div hide
      $("#grid-46-48").show();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#grid-44-46, #grid-46-48{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="radio" name="div-show-hide" id="input_radio-30-0-des" checked> Button One</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="div-show-hide" id="input_radio-30-1-des"> Button Two</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="div-show-hide" id="input_radio-30-2-des"> Button Three</label>

<div id="grid-40-42"><h2>Show - Div One</h2></div>
<div id="grid-44-46"><h2>Show - Div Two</h2></div>
<div id="grid-46-48"><h2>Show - Div Three</h2></div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, only change I made was to add $('#grid-44-46, #grid-46-48').hide(); before the on change event as @RaeeshAlam suggested in his comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use wild card to hide all `<div>` which id start with `grid-`  on radio change.

```js
$("[id^=grid-]").hide();
$('#input_radio-30-0-des').on('change', function() {
  $("[id^=grid-]").hide();
  var a = $(this).prop('checked');
  if (a) {
    $("#grid-40-42").show();
  } else {
    $("#grid-40-42").hide();
  }

});

$('#input_radio-30-1-des').on('change', function() {
  $("[id^=grid-]").hide();
  var a = $(this).prop('checked');
  if (a) {
    $("#grid-44-46").show();
  } else {
    $("#grid-44-46").hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' id='input_radio-30-0-des' name="group1" />
<div id='grid-40-42'>grid-40-42</div>
<input type='radio' id='input_radio-30-1-des' name="group1" />
<div id='grid-44-46'>grid-40-46</div>
```

**Note**

1. No need multi-pal `$(document).ready(function(){` .
2. Id must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Javascript object to match each Radio button with it's targeted div.
I assume they are hidden by default. Just having fun and giving an alternative to multiple checks! A cleaner code also where you could easily setup all those confusing names...

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
let matches = {
  "input_radio-30-0-des": 'grid-40-42',
  "input_radio-30-1-des": 'grid-44-46',
  "input_radio-30-2-des": 'grid-46-48'
};
$(":input[name='FM']").on("change", function () {
var target= matches[$(this).attr('id')];
  $('#' +target).toggle($(this).checked);
  $("[id^=grid-]").not('#' +target).hide();
})

});
```

```css
div[id*='grid-'] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="FM" id="input_radio-30-0-des" value="0"/>  
            <label for="input_radio-30-0-des">0</label>
            <input type="radio" name="FM" id="input_radio-30-1-des" value="1"/> 
            <label for="input_radio-30-1-des">1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="FM" id="input_radio-30-2-des" value="2"/> 
            <label for="input_radio-30-2-des">2</label>
            
            <div id="grid-40-42">40-42</div>
            <div id="grid-44-46">44-46</div>
            <div id="grid-46-48">46-48</div>
```